# How do people with a mathematics bachelors typically find a job after graduation in Germany?

Tags: mathematics, job-search, germany

I keep hearing that there are a ton of job opportunities for Mathematics bachelors, but what is still unclear to me is, how does a person, once obtained with a Mathematics degree, say in pure, find jobs to apply for in Germany?

Comment: Do you have a more specific question to ask? The answer to the one posted could be *the same way everybody else*. Contacts, job searching websites, linkedIn etc.

Comment: I mean, I don't think I have see in my life any place saying "Hiring requirement : Bachelors degree in Math". In India, normally the expectation is a person becomes professor or some bank job after mathematics degree. So, I am trying to figure out how it is different in Germany @kejtos

Comment: I reside in Czechia, but it is very likely very similar in Germany. Usually a "Uni degree" or a "Master's degree" would be there, rather than Bachelors, but plenty positions appreciate and some (though rarely) even require a Math degree. Having a math degree is a plus (at least) for plenty of positions in finance, logistics or data science.

Comment: @trystwithfreedom It's not different. People with a degree in pure maths predominantly don't end up working in pure maths. But that's not the same thing as saying they don't have job opportunities. Plenty of fields love math graduates, because they went through a fairly demanding program requiring strong analytical skills and abstract thinking. Business consulting, insurance, investment banking, all kinds of engineering (including, but not necessarily limited to, software), logistics and supply chain management, project management, or general management roles all come to mind.

Comment: Is this an “Academia” question?

Answer (score 0):

There are ton of jobs opportunities for Mathematics bachelors. Since a bachelor degree is generally obtained before one is 25 years old, there is plenty of time to retrain for any required skill.

Some jobs require some training&formation by the company, some other jobs require a complete shift in career.

There are tons of resources on how to find a job in Germany, so the question is a tad too broad. A good starting point is [this forum for immigrants to Germany](https://www.toytowngermany.com/).

Best of luck!

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question 'How does one find a job'